# Lodash _.memoize "Argument types do not match parameters"

Tags: typescript, lodash

For some reason I can't seem to get the IDE (IntelliJ) to not complain about this, any idea what the problem is? I thought memoize could take a function as a parameter:

```
declare var _: _.LoDashStatic;

export class MemoizeService {
    'use strict';

    masterCatTree;
    ...

    flattenTree = _.memoize(this._flattenTree);
    private _flattenTree(tree?: any, level?: number) {
        let level;
        const self = this;
        if (!tree) {
            tree = self.masterCatTree;
            level = 0;
        }

        let arr = [];
        if (tree) {
            for (let key in tree) {
                if (!tree.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    continue;
                }
                let val = angular.copy(tree[key]);
                if (level) {
                    val.name = _.times(level, _.constant('-')).join('') + ' ' + val.name;
                }
                arr.push(val);
                arr.push(...self.flattenTree(val.children, level + 1));
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

/*** Addendum ***/

The LodashStatic has the following info in the definition file

```
interface LoDashStatic {
    /**
     * Creates a function that memoizes the result of func. If resolver is provided it determines the cache key for
     * storing the result based on the arguments provided to the memoized function. By default, the first argument
     * provided to the memoized function is coerced to a string and used as the cache key. The func is invoked with
     * the this binding of the memoized function.
     * @param func The function to have its output memoized.
     * @param resolver The function to resolve the cache key.
     * @return Returns the new memoizing function.
     */
    memoize: {
        <T extends Function>(func: T, resolver?: Function): T & MemoizedFunction;
        Cache: MapCache;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using an up to date lodash.d.ts, and referencing it (either through `/// <reference` or `import`)?

Comment: Thanks for looking @MikeMcCaughan, I modified the code in the question. I'm using `declare var _: _.LoDashStatic;`

Comment: Also to note, I don't get such errors when I use `_.once` instead of `_.memoize` but in my function I don't want to use once.

Comment: Yeah, I'd try and find that .d.ts file that defines `memoize`. I think IntelliJ has the ability to "go to definition" of a function? Then you can see if it's taking a function as an argument there.

Comment: I added the following the info in the definition file. I can't really see anything wrong with it but I'm not really used to seeing definition files. Do you see anything?

Comment: No, that's fine. You probably don't even need the declaration at the top of the class file. It could be the line `flattenTree = _.memoize(this._flattenTree);`, which looks odd considering its placement. Perhaps add `public flattenTree;` to the class, then, in your constructor, put that line.

Comment: sadly it didn't work... so bizarre... I think I'll just manually implement memoization for the function... Thanks for your help though

Comment: Sure. BTW, sometimes using something like `_['memoize'](this._flattenTree)` can work, as it will "hide" the function name from the compiler. You could also do `(<any>_).memoize(this._flattenTree)`, which will essentially "re-type" the underscore so TypeScript won't try to resolve the reference. Good luck!

Comment: good call. I'm going to cycle back to it later but when I do I'll try see if it loads anyway regardless of the error. if it does I'll use a lookup access like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on a global declaration, you can always install the module declaration file: `typings install --save lodash`. If you explicitly `import * as _ from 'lodash'` at the top of your file, instead of `var _: _.LodashStatic`, everything should be fine.